# PhpExcel не работает на хостинге

Tags: phpexcel, php

Доброе время суток.

Есть веб-приложение, работает на php, используется phpExcel. На локальном хостинге (OpenServer) все работает нормально (из базы заполняется excel файл и отдается на скачивание).

Перенес все на платный хостинг, перестала работать функция обработки excel файла (ошибка `PHP open_basedir`, вроде). Написал хостеру, эту ошибку исправили, но теперь PhpExcel отдает мне вот это:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4MGTI0zlCcuTTltNTVtMFhhRjA/edit?usp=sharing
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался или, может, знает, в чем проблема? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @jkwe45, это появляется в том месте, где файл должен отдаваться на скачивание? Заголовки типа Content-Disposition на месте?

Comment: @Etki, это появляется в самом excel файле. Я предоставил сам файл, который выглядит не так, как нужно. Могу так же предоставить нормальный файл Excel'я, который "генерируется" на локальном сервере нормально, как и должен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел простое решение проболемы:

```
  ob_end_clean();
```